# @Angular - Common chunk gets lazy loaded content on build

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, webpack-2

if lazy loaded module uses some common code used only in that lazy module, the specific common code/module gets in common chunk on build, this increases first load time of all the other pages.

pseudo code below.

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
{ path: 'order', loadChildren: 'OrderModule' }
```

**order.routing.module.ts**

```
{ path: 'cart', loadChildren: 'CartModule' },
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: 'LoginModule' },
{ path: 'reviewcart', loadChildren: 'ReviewCartModule' }
```

**CartModule.ts**

```
imports: [OrderSharedModule]
```

**ReviewCartModule.ts**

```
imports: [OrderSharedModule]
```

the **OrderSharedModule** gets in **common.chunk.js**

> ng version

```
@angular/cli: 1.3.0-beta.1
node: 6.11.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.0
@angular/common: 4.3.0
@angular/compiler: 4.3.0
@angular/core: 4.3.0
@angular/forms: 4.3.0
@angular/http: 4.3.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.0
@angular/platform-server: 4.3.0
@angular/router: 4.3.0
@angular/cli: 1.3.0-beta.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.0
@angular/language-service: 4.3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This issue is discussed here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7021

You can workaround it by disabling the `commonChunk` option in `.angular-cli.json`, like so:

```
{ 
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    ...
    "build": {
      "commonChunk": false
    }
  }
}
```

But bear in mind this will mean there is no longer a common.chunk.js file and all shared dependencies, e.g. **OrderSharedModule**, will be duplicated in each module that requires them.

Not great.

I'm looking for a better solution at the moment...

Comment: Have you found a better solution?